How to select value from polars/rust dataframe
I have data frame created with rust/polars.
I need a script that allows me by index get values and filter another dataframe based on selection.
Here is the code and data structure I have:
Here is USER_INFO df:
┌───────────────────────┬──────────────┬────────────────┐
│ email                 ┆ user_role    ┆ user_countries │
│ ---                   ┆ ---          ┆ ---            │
│ str                   ┆ str          ┆ list[str]      │
╞═══════════════════════╪══════════════╪════════════════╡
│ test@test.com         ┆ customer     ┆ ["USA", "UK"]. │

From this data frame I have to get countries probaby in vector format (Note I have over 100 records in DF) and filter DF below lets call it SHOPS_INFO:
┌─────────┬───────────────────────┬──────────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ country ┆ partner               ┆ resource         ┆ amount       ┆ item         │
│ ---     ┆ ---                   ┆ ---              ┆ ---          ┆ ---          │
│ str     ┆ str                   ┆ str              ┆ str          ┆ str          │
╞═════════╪═══════════════════════╪══════════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ USA     ┆ WALMART               ┆ net              ┆ one dollar   ┆ Goveee       │

Here is the code I prepared:
    // Take the countries of the first user in USER_INFO
    let first_user_countries = USER_INFO
        .column("user_countries")?
        .get(0);

    // apply the filter on a SHOPS_INFO
    let filtered_df = SHOPS_INFO
        .clone()
        .lazy()
        .filter(col("country").is_in(lit(&first_user_countries)))
        .collect()?;

    println!("{:?}", filtered_df);

It throws error
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&Result<polars::prelude::AnyValue<'_>, PolarsError>: polars::prelude::Literal` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:70:42
    |
70  |         .filter(col("country").is_in(lit(&first_user_countries)))
    |                                      --- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `polars::prelude::Literal` is not implemented for `&Result<polars::prelude::AnyValue<'_>, PolarsError>`

but if I define countries in a static way code works
    // apply the filter on a SHOPS_INFO
    let filtered_df = SHOPS_INFO
        .clone()
        .lazy()
        .filter(col("country").is_in(lit(Series::new("".into(), ["USA"]))))
        .collect()?;
    println!("{:?}", filtered_df);


Neither Result nor AnyValue implement the required Literal trait, but it's not difficult at all to get the Series which does implement it out of the PolarsResult<AnyValue>:
    let AnyValue::List(first_user_countries) = user_info.column("user_countries")?.get(0)? else {
        polars_bail!(ShapeMismatch: "invalid datatype of column `user_countries`");
    };

    let filtered_df = shops_info
        .lazy()
        .filter(col("country").is_in(lit(first_user_countries)))
        .collect()?;

Literal is only implemented for owned Series so I've also removed the borrow, if you need to keep it around, you'll have to clone it.

How to import polars_bail ?

https://docs.rs/polars/0.43.1/polars/?search=bail But anything that diverges works like return …, panic!, etc.
